# Linux Gpio V2 request line ioctl failing

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, gpio

I'm trying to implement the new linux gpio api. Using the v1 api, I was able to confirm that this code works:

```c
// req is part of larger code
struct gpiohandle_request lreq;
memset(lreq.default_values, 0, sizeof(lreq.default_values));
strcpy(lreq.consumer_label, "TESTIO");
lreq.lines = req.bank_count[bank];
lreq.flags = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;

for (int line = 0; line < lreq.lines; line++)
  lreq.lineoffsets[line] = req.pins[bank][line];

if (ioctl(bank_fd[bank], GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &lreq) < 0) {
  std::cerr << "Error on chip io\n";
  return -1;
}
```

However, when I try to switch to v2:

```c
struct gpio_v2_line_request lreq;
lreq.config.flags = GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_OUTPUT;
lreq.config.num_attrs = 0;
strcpy(lreq.consumer, "TESTIO");
lreq.num_lines = req.bank_count[bank];

for (int line = 0; line < lreq.num_lines; line++) {
  lreq.offsets[line] = req.pins[bank][line];
}

if (ioctl(bank_fd[bank], GPIO_V2_GET_LINE_IOCTL, &lreq) < 0) {
  std::cerr << "Error on chip io\n";
  return -1;
}
```

my ioctl always fails with `errno` 22

I'm not sure what the equivalent of `memset(lreq.default_values, 0, sizeof(lreq.default_values))` is

Comment: I am having this problem as well, but with their library-provided function `gpiod_chip_request_lines`. I kept getting errors and after entering gdb, i found the ioctl call is what fails giving EINVAL. They zero the memory however: 
`memset(&uapi_req, 0, sizeof(uapi_req));
ret = ioctl(chip->fd, GPIO_V2_GET_LINE_IOCTL, &uapi_req);` 
Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: @lrdewaal not sure, that's strange since before that ioctl it calls
`ret = read_chip_info(chip->fd, &info);`

and read_chip_info does `ret = ioctl(fd, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, info);` so if your fd was invalid it should've failed [there...](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/lib/chip.c#n75)

Comment: Yeah that's what I am confused about too, so I suspect it has something to do with the request type GPIO_V2_GET_LINE_IOCTL. Whats even more odd though, is that it works for some lines but after requesting a couple of lines this ioctl call fails @mjkpolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to simply do this first:

```c
memset(&lreq, 0, sizeof(lreq));
```

I guess that is the equivalent of the default values. Found in the master branch of libgpiod [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/lib/chip.c#n228)

Comment: Yeah, this is 101 for any IOCTL programming.